# How to include a User ID object in an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, mongoose

I am starting to learn web development and I have a client server project where a user can authenticate then store their blood pressure readings. I have the authentication part working but struggeling with storing a blood pressure reading. I have verified that all of the features work using curl but I get errors from the server when I try to create a blood pressure reading. I think my issue is that I do not know how to include the User ID as an object in the Ajax call. Any help would be most appreciated.

Here is the curl script that works:

```
API="http://localhost:4741"
URL_PATH="/readings"

curl "${API}${URL_PATH}" \
  --include \
  --request POST \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
  --data '{
    "reading": {
      "systolic": "'"${S}"'",
      "diastolic": "'"${D}"'",
      "pulse": "'"${P}"'"
    }
  }'

echo
```

Below is the schema for the blood pressure reading:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const readingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  systolic: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  diastolic: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  pulse: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Reading', readingSchema)
```

Below is the blood pressure reading route that was created on the server app:

```
// CREATE
// POST /readings
router.post('/readings', requireToken, (req, res, next) => {
  // set owner of new reading to be current user
  req.body.reading.owner = req.user.id

  Reading.create(req.body.reading)
    // respond to succesful `create` with status 201 and JSON of new "reading"
    .then(reading => {
      res.status(201).json({ reading: reading.toObject() })
    })
    // if an error occurs, pass it off to our error handler
    // the error handler needs the error message and the `res` object so that it
    // can send an error message back to the client
    .catch(next)
})
```

Here is the Ajax call to the API.

```
// Create a reading
const readingCreate = function (data) {
  let dataToSend = [{ user: store.user._id }, { data }]
    dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ dataToSend })
  return $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: config.apiUrl + '/readings',
    data: dataToSend,
    headers: {
      ContentType: 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + store.user.token
     }
  })
}
```

This is what I can see from Chrome Dev tools:

From Chrome Network Headers:

Request URL: http://localhost:4741/readings
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: [::1]:4741
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request HEaders:

Accept: /
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Authorization: Bearer 62613675961deb85f4f11ecfca5239ac
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 30
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
ContentType: application/json
Host: localhost:4741
Origin: http://localhost:7165
Referer: http://localhost:7165/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36

This is what the server console says:

20:47:52 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time):
TypeError: Cannot set property 'owner' of undefined
at router.post (/Users/Ken/sei/projects/project2/bp_tracker/app/routes/reading_routes.js:62:26)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an array with user ID, but assigning the value of `req.user.id` instead of `req.body.user` to `reading.owner` for some reason.